# Problem with online hosted json file and to Post them per c# HttpClient

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, httprequest, httpclient

Im programming an C# Android App and I store my data on the website jsonbin.io I already used this website already in a javascript project, it worked fine there. Reading of the data is already implemented and working, but not the function to post. On the website you have to put a so-called X-Master-Key in the header for verification.

[JSONBIN Link](https://jsonbin.io)

The working code of the HttpRequest:

```
           WebRequest web = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.jsonbin.io/b/"BIN-CODE"/latest");
        web.Headers.Add("X-Master-Key:THE-MASTER-KEY");
        web.GetResponse();
        HttpWebResponse response = web.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            json = reader.ReadToEnd()
        }
```

The working code with the reading and writing part from my JavaScript Project:

```
 writeJSON: function()
{
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    req.open("PUT", "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/"BIN-CODE"", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("X-Master-Key", "THE-MASTER-KEY");
    
    req.send(JSON.stringify(this.file));
},
readJSON: async function () {
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
   
    let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
    req.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (req.readyState == 4) {
        this.file= JSON.parse(req.responseText);
      }
    
    };
    
    req.open("GET", "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/"BIN-CODE"/latest", true);
    req.setRequestHeader("X-Master-Key", "THE-MASTER-KEY");
    req.send();
  
}
```

Here are also some pictures of the website for a better understanding:

[editting the JSON on the Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUJ81.png)

[call up the URL which is also addressed in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nspH.png)

Comment: I am sorry but where did you find the code examples. Nothing personal, but it looks  like an assembler for me. Why you just don't use good old jquery ajax? All this code  you could put in several lines. Try to google and you will get hundreds examples.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to do a http post / put in c #

Comment: then please edit your question to actually state that.  But there are thousands of questions about HTTP Post/Put in C#, have you tried anything yet?  https://www.google.com/search?q=http+post+c%23+site:stackoverflow.com